# String or binary data would be truncated, values are within the range of Size

Tags: sql-server, database

I am using microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I received a problem while inserting values. The error message is called **String or binary data would be truncated** . Before posting, I have looked at other similar posts and I still could do not understand why I got this error. The weird thing is that when I set my ActivityDesc column with varchar(500) it works!! Why can't I set it to varchar(400)? The value is clearly within 400 words.

```
Create Table Activity
(ActivityCd         char(6)         not null,           
PrerequsiteCd       char(6)         null,    
ActivityTitle       varchar(50)     not null,  
ActivityDesc        varchar(400)    null,       
Primary Key (ActivityCd),
Foreign Key (PrerequsiteCd) References Activity (ActivityCd))
```

--------------------------------------------Inserting values--------------------

```
Insert into Activity
(ActivityCd, PrerequsiteCd, ActivityTitle, ActivityDesc)
values
('C26212', NULL, 'Computer Introduction', 'This activity teaches you the
basic knowledge of how to operate and use a computer. For instance, 
participants will be taught how to use and operate a mouse and keyboard. 
Furthermore, they will also be taught how to surf the internet. Besides 
that, to make IT safe and friendly for users, they will be brief on the 
importance of installing an anti virus program to keep their computers safe from malware')
```

Comment: no, it is length is 402

Comment: According to Notepad++, the ActivityDesc string you supplied is 412 characters long, thus over the 400 that you are setting your column size to.

Comment: @Diado How is this so? I thought its only around 71 characters to be exact? Isn't characters the same as words?

Comment: @sanatsathyan How is this so? I thought its only around 71 characters to be exact? Isn't characters the same as words?

Comment: @XxS0ul678 A character is an individual letter, number or whiespace, not an entire word.

Comment: @XxS0ul678, you are right, it is 71 words exactly, but 402 characters.

Comment: @sanatsathyan how foolish of me...... Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Diado how foolish of me...... Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

VARCHAR(n) can accept any length of character string up to n characters in length (not words). And your input contains more than 400 characters.

Refer [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089(v=sql.110).aspx) for complete details of usage.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your "ActivityDesc" column value length is greater than 400 which you have specified at the time of table creation.

i have checked the length of your data in 412 which is more than 400 thats why you are getting this error.

Thanks